# Why didn't Naruto and Sasuke feel a disruption in their chakra when Madara and Hashirama were reanimated?

Tags: naruto

Hagoromo stated that, when Indra and Ashura reincarnate, their chakra dwells inside you as well. And its shown that Edo Tensei shinobi regain everything they've lost when reanimated, such as when BOTH Madara and Nagato had a rinnegan. So, Hashirama and Madara should've regained Indra and Ashura's chakra, as when reincarnated it is in you. So, since you regain everything you've lost, Naruto and Sasuke would have had their chakra, as Hashirama and Madara. There'd be two Indra's and two Ashura's, so shouldn't  Naruto and Sasuke felt a disruption in their chakra when Hashirama and Madara got revived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but no, one because they don't feel a disruption in their chakra, but in general, as long as Naruto or Sasuke had some form of sage mode enabled, then sage mode would allow them to sense a strong appearance of chakra. Naruto would be able to sense all the Kage as well as Sasuke and all the Edo Tensei, ever sense the war ark started... so PLOT HOLE.